# Command to quit[cleanly] GUI applications from a tty?

Tags: command-line

While running alpha/beta Ubuntu, I have often had problems where X freezes and I would have to restart X.

During this freeze, I'm able to switch to a tty and shutdown the programs. I either use top and kill the running apps[evolution/firefox/etc,..], or use killall commands.

But when I use those kill commands, the application shuts-down abruptly and when opening in the next session it 'recovers'. ex: Firefox needs to restore all the web-pages I was viewing, so if I had 20-30 tabs open it will literally freeze for a few mins. evolution would not have deleted messages in trash, etc..

Is there a command I can use to shutdown applications cleanly from a tty? 
[apps that i use regularly are firefox,evolution,transmission,xchat]

Comment: I don't know much about X internals, but I guess you could somehow  deliver the close window event to the proper window handler, however it would not work on your case because X itself which haandles the messages is hang. To make things even more complex most of those apps have additional prompts when they are closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to notify a POSIX application to close, while still having a grace period to do cleanup is to send it the [`SIGTERM` (wikipedia link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTERM) signal. The [`SIGKILL` (wikipedia link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL) signal, on the other hand, kills the application without even giving it a chance to tidy up.

However… both of your actions - calling `top` (by the way I would recommend that you switch to use `htop` instead of `top`) or `killall` - send the `SIGTERM` signal by default.

And I have just tested firing Firefox up - and trying it both with `SIGKILL` and `SIGTERM`. With `SIGTERM`, when I took Firefox again, I did not get any error or "restoration" message. With `SIGKILL`, I got the `it's embarrassing` screen.

So, the reason is simple: **The instance of X for these apps is *frozen***. All these GUI applications operate under the premise that their instance of X is functioning properly. They probably cannot even try anything if X is frozen.

The way to solve your problem is to determine why X is freezing, and prevent that from happening.

**Edit**: Ah, sorry -  just saw that you talk about using the Ubuntu alpha/beta when X freezes. In which case… I would say it is part of the excitement of running an alpha/beta. Try to understand why it freezes, write/add to a bug report. In order to speed Firefox's startup in these, simply tell it to not reload the same tabs when it reopens. (You can still find these tabs in history). For the other applications, their cleanup actions are rather trivial - it should not cost you much that they didn't happen.

Comment: Yea, sending '$ kill -TERM PID' _at times_ does seem to be better. Oh! and I do report bugs. ;)

Comment: @Vish: `SIGTERM` is the default signal for most task-killing programs. There is no reason why `kill -TERM $PID` would have better results than using `top` or `killall` with the default parameters.

Comment: Ah, then it was just my head making it _seem_ better. - I wonder if system monitor does anything different with its end/kill process. Someone should write an universal 'Quit' command. And make it industrial standard. ;p

Comment: @Vish: As far as I know, System Monitor sends a `SIGTERM` when you use it to end a process. And a `SIGKILL` if the app hasn't exited after some time / if the user tries it again (and Windows does something nearly identical). I could be mistaken though, as I rarely use the System Monitor.

Comment: Since the closest ans seems to be _no such command_ . jhominal's answer is the closest. But it does not solve the issue though. - not sure if this question can be marked solved but it seems 'answered' ;).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both `browser.sessionstore.enabled` and `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash` set to true in about:config? Seems to have worked for me :)

Comment: Yeah, i do have them, but i was looking to for a command for all apps, like a 'killall $foo'.  (but a cleaner quit one)

Comment: As intimated elsewhere `killall` sends SIGTERM which tells the application to close rather than killing it; applications close promptly though so won't do the housekeeping - clean trash, etc. - that you want them to do. It sounds like you want to send the application a command that causes it to do `File > Quit`? You might want to look at the `xdotool` - it can send a particular key sequence to a particular window from a script, so you could raise a window, File > Quit and respond to the "are you sure" dialog(s).

Answer (score -1):

hello i guess to reboot your machine nicely just hold the right ALT+sysReq then type REUISB and it will reboot those letters has a meaning but im not sue but you can search for it i hop it will help

peace out